# Data Visualization: Summary Statistics

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, tables

I have 10,463 observations of crop yield data, however, they are subdivided into 6 crops (~2000 obs each). I am wondering if it is best to report a summary statistics table by crop (maybe 3 crops per table for two tables) or to just report the overall statistics? I find the latter difficult to settle on as it is hard to compare the crop yields between certain crops that have a large differences between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could depend on the reason you are reporting a value, but it seems to me that you'd want to separate the values by crop. There's no reason to expect corn and grapes to behave the same way.

Indeed, separating by group is the goal of the whole statistical field of *regression* where we tighten up our uncertainty about a value by using some other information about that observation (we expect an adult to be taller than a child, for instance). Instead of expecting that adults and children will have different heights, you expect different crops to have different yields.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I am doing regression analysis and wanted to introduce the characteristics of my data exactly as you have stated I was just unsure if it was commonplace or not.